# Understanding and using the clause "May it please ..."

Tags: clauses

I have seen this:

> **May it please the court**, I do not aim to go there.

What would you say is the grammatical function of **May it please the court**?

*Please* seems to be a verb here, and it seems to be intransitive, with no object, as in *He was pleased*.  Its subject argument seems to be *it*, and *may* seems to be an auxiliary verb.

Should I understand this as a dependent clause? Must I write it like this?

> It may please the court, . . .

Or may I write it as an independent clause:

> It may please the court.

And may I use it like this and get a complete sentence?

> I may like to speak to you, **may it please you to**.

Or may I write

> **May it please you to**, I may like to speak to you.

Comment: Do you have a book on basic English grammar? Your questions are really hard to understand with all the *seems* and *mays* in them. Read anything in English, except your own questions: How often is the word *seems* used? A great deal less than you use it. That's why I suggest, not for the first time, that you concentrate on some **basic sentence construction**.

Comment: @pazzo The word "seems" is used rather a lot when describing one's uncertainty about a situation. ELL questionsusually describe uncertainty, often in the form of "I think that X works like Y but I'm not sure." I don't see the relevance of comparing the frequency of "seems" in ELL questions with its frequency in general English text.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have read dozens of saySay's questions. To me, he/she uses *seems* as an equivalent to the verb *to be*. This is from their very first question, even in constructions which clearly are not expressing uncertainty. I think the OP really does not understand how to put a basic English sentence together. Nor have they shown anything but a grasping (but not a grasp) of parts of speech. The user would benefit greatly by learning basic grammar points.

Comment: @pazzo I think OP is fundamentally confused with how English expresses modality. saySay appears to  understand *seem* as a sort of "modal copula" --basically what we ordinarily express with *may be*-- and to *may* as  sort of "generic modal" employed to express any degree of undertainty. I'm reluctant to close any question on this basis; modality is one of the trickiest points of our language. But with goodwill and imagination I think it's possible to understand what saySay is asking.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm really trying to help the guy/gal. But I can't understand his/her English. To me, beginning with the basics is the route l would go face-to-face  rather than trying to decode their idiosyncratic uses, especially of *seems*, which fills the posts of saySay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pragmatically**, *May it please the court* is an archaic formula expressing the speaker's deference to a presiding judge: an acknowledgment that strictly speaking nothing may occur (and nothing may be omitted) in the courtroom without the judge's permission.

The **syntax**—the part of the meaning which is expressed by the order and relationship of different words—is complex.

- In this particular forumula, *please* is an ordinary transitive verb. *It* (which refers to the main clause which follows) is its subject and *the Court* is its object. *Please* itself is cast in the infinitive (non-tensed, non-inflected) form because it is the complement of the modal auxiliary verb *may*, which is the finite head verb of this clause.
- Internally, the inversion of *may* with its subject (*may it* instead of *it may*) signals that *may* bears an *optative*<sup>∗</sup> sense—it expresses a wish or hope.

  > May you be forgiven! = *I hope that you will be forgiven.*
  >   May God strike me dead if I am lying = *I hope that God will strike me dead*
  >   May it please the Court = *I hope that it will please the Court.*

  Such optative clauses ***may*** stand on their own as independent clauses, as they do in my first two examples. In this case, however . . .
- Externally, the formula acts like a condition clause (an *if* clause or *protasis*) in a conditional construction of the sort that Declerk and Reed<sup>†</sup> call a ‘Performative-Q Utterance conditional’. In fact, it can also be expressed as a frank *if* clause: ***If*** it please the Court.

  It expresses a necessary condition for the following consequence clause; it is semantically equivalent to

  > I only say what follows ***if*** it pleases the Court that I do so.

The expression is entirely archaic, used nowhere except in the courts and by nobody except lawyers; I can think of no other situation in which such extreme deference is called for. (It may be that formal addresses to the Queen are prefaced with ‘May it please your Majesty’, but that is not a situation likely to arise for most of us.) It should not be emulated in ordinary speech or writing. In most contexts the Present-day English equivalent is a simple *Please*:

> I would like to speak with you, please.
>   Please, I would like to speak with you.

In these, *please* is no longer understood by native speakers to be any sort of verb; it is merely a "discourse marker" expressing politeness in making a request.

---

<sup>∗</sup> *Optative* is a technical term signifying a particular [*modality*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality) which marks a sentence as having some meaning distinct from an ordinary assertion of fact. Linguists have had to name many such *modalities*, because every language has different ways of expressing different shades of meaning.

- Some languages use distinct inflections of the verb to express particular *modalities*--for instance, the *subjunctive* inflections in many European languages may express modality, among many other things.
- In other cases *modality* may be expressed by particular words; in English, for instance, *possibly* (epistemic modality), *wish* or *hope*(optative modality), *let's* (modality), and so forth.

English also has a very small number of verbs (*can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would*) with distinct syntactic properties which are called *modal verbs* because they are ordinarily used *only* to express modality. Unhappily, they are called upon to express many different sorts of modality, so it is very difficult to learn how to use them properly.

<sup>†</sup> *Conditionals:A Comprehensive Empirical Analysis*, Mouton de Gruyter 2001.

Comment: In *May it please the Court* *May it please the Court* may get discerned optative? May optative seem like subjunctive, cohortative, and, or, maybe something like jussive? *May it please the Court* may seem like a conditional (dependent[?]) clause, a protasis that goes to an apodosis?
Maybe, *May it please the Court, X.* So *May it please the Court* may not stand a dependent clause? So I think *please* may seem a modal, subjunctive verb? I may not get utilization of modal verbs? (And *syntax* mostly signifies where words get placed?)

Comment: I always hear lawyers say "if it pleases the court" ... but that could just be a film thing... I don't spend much time in courts.

Comment: @saySay I hope you find that my additions answer your questions. I must tell you that you are dealing here with several very complex English language issues. I certainly don't know all the answers to them, and for some of them **nobody** has answers that all professional linguists agree on! :) Don't let me discourage you; you may be someone who will learn the language most easily  through this sort of approach; but it is going to be very hard going, and you do not yet have the tools to express your questions clearly. . . . *continued*

Comment: So you may want to do some more reading on the site, and in particular look at those of your questions which I have rewritten to see how you might express yourself more idiomatically. *Seem* and *may* are not used in English quite the way you have been using them.

Comment: @Catija Yes, the ordinary 3pnsg *pleases* is a much more contemporary way of expressing the old formula.

Comment: I thank you, StoneyB. I do think I may like aiming to do it like this. I think you get what I may do text on. I think that information you get me I mostly get. I appreciate it. I thank you.